# javascript windows.location string picking

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, get, href

I have this URL:

```
http://localhost/estamo/asset.php?aname=VklQIFBsYXph&di=Ng==
```

And I will need get that using Javascript

```
var locat = window.location.href;     
$.get("enviaramigo.php?email="+$("#email").val()+"&url="+locat, function(html) {
```

But, when I use the *locat* var, I will get this incomplete URL:

```
http://localhost/estamo/asset.php?aname=VklQIFBsYXph
```

How to I get the complete URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the url using encodeURIComponent

```
var locat = window.location.href;     
$.get("enviaramigo.php?email="+$("#email").val()+"&url="+encodeURIComponent(locat), function(html) {
```

or base64

```
$.get("enviaramigo.php?email="+$("#email").val()+"&url="+btoa(locat), function(html) {
```

and you will need to decode on the sever.